# How to convert command for cmd to command for batch-script

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Sorry by stupid question, but i try correctly convert my cmd-command to batch-command already 30 minutes. I have got workly command for cmd:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\SmartBear\TestComplete 12\Bin\TestComplete.exe" "C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\TestComplete 12 Projects\TestProject1\TestProject1.pjs" /r p:TestProject1 /e
```

In batch file, i want render paths to variables. For examples:

```
set testCompleteDirectiore_volBat = C:\Program Files (x86)\SmartBear\TestComplete 12\Bin\TestComplete.exe
set testCompleteProjectDirectory_volBat = C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\TestComplete 12 Projects\TestProject1\TestProject1.pjs
set nameProject_volBat = TestProject
call %testCompleteDirectiore_volBat% %testCompleteProjectDirectory_volBat% /r p:%nameProject_volBat% /e
```

When i try run my batch, i get exception:

```
'/r' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

When i used:

```
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\SmartBear\TestComplete 12\Bin\TestComplete.exe" "C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\TestComplete 12 Projects\TestProject1\TestProject1.pjs" /r p:TestProject1 /e
```

all work. Where my mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove all spaces surrounding `=` equals sign in `set` commands and use double quotes as follows:

```
set "testCompleteDirectiore_volBat=C:\Program Files (x86)\SmartBear\TestComplete 12\Bin\TestComplete.exe"
set "testCompleteProjectDirectory_volBat=C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\TestComplete 12 Projects\TestProject1\TestProject1.pjs"
set "nameProject_volBat=TestProject"
call "%testCompleteDirectiore_volBat%" "%testCompleteProjectDirectory_volBat%" /r p:%nameProject_volBat% /e
```

**Otherwise**, a space left from `=` becomes a trailing character in **variable name** and a space right from `=` becomes a leading character in **variable value**, e.g.

```
                                 ↓
set testCompleteDirectiore_volBat = C:\Program Files (x86)\SmartBear\TestComplete 12\Bin\TestComplete.exe
                                   ↑
                                    ↓
echo "%testCompleteDirectiore_volBat %"
" C:\Program Files (x86)\SmartBear\TestComplete 12\Bin\TestComplete.exe"
 ↑
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove spaces in the assignments operators before and after '=', i.e.
instead of

```
set var1 = someval1
```

try

```
set var1=someval1
```